# Symfony 404 error is shown after trying to login to Backend app

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, backend

I have a website that per original developer "was working" on local environment. I have configured that website on Windows 2008 Server with IIS 7. Website itself (frontend app) is working fine but backend app is throwing 404 error page after trying to login.

Project Configuration file has all plugins listed as enabled and MySQL database was updated using the data from fixtures.

After trying to login page is redirected to **domain.com/login** and **404 error** message is shown.

Are there any specific routines that should be added for /login to work?

I have compared the settings with the ones specified at [tutorial](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/13).

```
login_module:    sfGuardAuth
login_action:    signin
```

Comment: Did you try on dev controller: domain.com/backend_dev.php/login ?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have this version - I have received only backend.php

Comment: Then create it ! Like this one: http://svn.jobeet.org/trunk/web/backend_dev.php

Comment: will try this later today; thanks

Comment: That works - at least login is functioning for backend_dev.php. Where should I look for differences? Please advise

Comment: Seems I have found the reason - changed:

no_script_name:         true to
no_script_name:         false

for prod

It works now for login, but I see a lot of 404 error messages for CSS/JS within firefox; is this known issue? I will dig further on this.

Comment: To fix this issue I have just copied content of the corresponding /web folder for each plugin to /web/pluginName/css, /web/pluginName/js and /web/pluginName/images but I think there should be some other solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the dev mode enable now, you should run `php symfony plugin:publish-assets`. It will move or create a symlink to each `/web` folder for all your plugin.